# Constant [Error 2] when running scripts in Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text 2. A recent script I was working on kept giving me a constant [Error 2] message. I then realized it was doing this for **all** of my scripts, even something as simple as (print "Hello World!"). Based on the details of the error message, it seems the interpreter is pointing to some sort of path and I have no idea how it got like that. How can I fix this? Thanks!

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified 
[cmd:  [u'python', u'-u', u'C:\\Users\\Sam\\Desktop\\hello.py']]
[dir:  C:\Users\Sam\Desktop]
[path: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common      
Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows 
Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\
System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program  
Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\]
```

[Finished]

Answer (score 2):

looks like you dont have python in your path

you either need to add it to your path (if its installed)

or

you need to install python ...